# Java regular expression to match patterns in url

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of urls that share the following pattern:

```
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Crosman-Pumpmaster-760-Pump-177-Pellet-4-5-mm-BB-Air-Rifle-Black-760B-/251635693266?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a96a7f6d2
```

I want to extract `item3a96a7f6d2`. The `http://www.ebay.com/itm/` and `&hash=` are fixed patterns while the string in between can change. I wrote:

```
                String prodPatternString = "(http://www.ebay.com/itm/)(.*?)(hash=)(.*?)";
                Pattern prodPattern = Pattern.compile(prodPatternString);
                Matcher prodMatcher = prodPattern.matcher(prodUrl);
                while(prodMatcher.find()){
                    String pid = matcher.group(4);
                }
```

But it gives me an error saying "No match found". Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `matcher.group(4);` line to `prodMatcher.group(4);`  and then remove the `?` present inside the last capturing group because `.*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters, so it would match also an empty string even though characters present since it's in non-greedy form.

```
String prodUrl = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Crosman-Pumpmaster-760-Pump-177-Pellet-4-5-mm-BB-Air-Rifle-Black-760B-/251635693266?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a96a7f6d2";
String prodPatternString = "(http://www.ebay.com/itm/)(.*?)(hash=)(.*)";
Pattern prodPattern = Pattern.compile(prodPatternString);
Matcher prodMatcher = prodPattern.matcher(prodUrl);
while(prodMatcher.find()){
        String pid = prodMatcher.group(4);
        System.out.println(pid);
}
```

Output:

```
item3a96a7f6d2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still don't understand why the ? needs to be removed in the last capturing group while it is needed in the second capturing group? I think these two patterns are the same. Thanks

Comment: no both are different. It's based on the following pattern. `.*?` in this regex `http://www.ebay.com/itm/.*?hash=` matches all the characters which are next to `http://www.ebay.com/itm/`, upto `hash=` . But `.*?` in `hash=.*?` matches an empty character because there isn't a pattern following the `.*?` and `.*?` will do a shortest possible match. So here the shortest possible match is an empty string since `*` repeats the previous char zero or more times.

Comment: you could check what i said with `(hash=)(.*?)$`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [lastindexof](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm) method. Then you can substring the url starting at the last index of '&hash=' and ending at the full length of the string. This will get the item=x

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(http://www.ebay.com/itm/)(.*?)(hash=)([^&]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY1yX1/1)

`.*?` is matching too little in the 4th capturing group in your regex.